# Turn off FullPage.js below 767px

Tags: fullpage.js

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if(screen.width < 767){
   jQuery.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);
  }
   else{
  jQuery('#fullpage').fullpage({
   scrollBar:true,
   afterRender: function(){
   jQuery('.hslider_misc_holder').each(function(){
   var hslider_slider_id = jQuery(this).attr('id').slice(8);
   activate_width_checker(1080, 1080, 'responsive', hslider_slider_id);
  });
  }
  });
   }


 });
```

I'm trying to turn off fullpage.js below 767px the current function is to turn off auto scroll, no matter what solution I try I can't stop the effect!!!

Ideally I want it turned off entirely.

Help appreciated

Ant

Answer (score 0):

Use the fullpage.js responsive options: `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight`.

From [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **responsiveWidth:** (default 0) A normal scroll (autoScrolling:false) will be used under the defined width in pixels. A class fp-responsive is added to the body tag in case the user wants to use it for his own responsive CSS. For example, if set to 900, whenever the browser's width is less than 900 the plugin will scroll like a normal site.
>
> **responsiveHeight:** (default 0) A normal scroll (autoScrolling:false) will be used under the defined height in pixels. A class fp-responsive is added to the body tag in case the user wants to use it for his own responsive CSS. For example, if set to 900, whenever the browser's height is less than 900 the plugin will scroll like a normal site.

[Example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html) (code available in github examples folder)

Comment: Thanks I set that up at 767. But the scrolling on mobile was very poor as a consequence. Slow and becoming stuck in places. I don't know if I missed something!!

Comment: As you can see, that's not the case with [the example page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html). Fullpage.js has no control hover the scroll on responsive mode.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. it would be nice to have it working on laptop and desktop!! I'll look deeper into it, when I have more time!!